# Normals Inverted

Tags: normals

The normals on the "cube"s, for some reason, appear inverted. They look inside out. I've tried recalculating normals but it still isn't working. I'm a bit of a beginner so what should I do?

Edit: Fixed. Didn't select all faces in recalculating normals.

Comment: Without opening the file you either have -1 scaling or your normals are actually inverted in the .blend file as well. Blender by default shows you both sides of the faces, you need to enable "Backface Culling" in the 3D view properties or enable normal display in edit mode to see which way they are actually facing.

Comment: Thanks I checked with backface culling and they are inverted in blender. I've tried recalculating normals but it still isn't fixed. I'm a bit of a beginner so what should I do?

Comment: Recalculating normals SHOULD work for a simple cube, did you have all the faces selected? Anyway you can flip normals of selected faces using CTRL+F menu in edit mode.

Comment: Ah thank you. I didn't select all faces.  It seems such a stupid mistake now. So should I answer my own question for others or delete it? I don't know all the rules of this site properly